# F# hidden mutation

Tags: f#

Anyone have a decent example, preferably practical/useful, they could post demonstrating the concept?

I came across this term somewhere that I’m unable to find, probably it has to do something with a function returning a function while enclosing on some mutable variable. So there’s no visible mutation.

Probably Haskell community has originated the idea where mutation happens in another area not visible to the scope. I maybe vague here so seeking help to understand more.

Comment: Computation expression (aka monad)?

Comment: Samantha, I don’t think so, it’s something else, like how mutation or side effects is handled in pure functional programming languages like Haskell. We may call it hidden side effects.

Comment: Haskell is not really relevant to F#. The idea is to encapsulate mutation in a private function or a closure, as you point out in your second paragraph.

Comment: @s952163 thanks, let me add more to it, they say pure functional programming shouldn't have side effects, and I'm trying to quote them again, they do it in a way where IO is handled somewhere else and it appears to be a pure functional approach. that statement was very vague to me, so will be to you i guess. is there something like this?

Comment: Who is `them`? F# is not a pure FP language. Only academic languages go to this extremel, they are useful, but not in an applied sense. I.e. if you want to get something done you will have to do IO, and it's very easy in F#. You can definitely [study Haskell](learnyouahaskell.com/). Regarding `IO`, the problem with it in a lazy language like Haskell is that the order of the operation is not defined, so when you do `IO` the operations are forced to be in order (basically a sequence of nested functions). In fact a similar issue happens in F# when you use `seq`, you have to manifest it before IO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good idea to hide mutation, so the consumers of the API won't inadvartently change something unexpectedly. This just means that you have to encapsulate your mutable data/state. This can be done via objects (yes, objects), but what you are referring to in your question can be done with a closure, the canonical example is a counter:

```
let countUp =
    let mutable count = 0
    (fun () -> count <- count + 1
               count)

countUp() // 1
countUp() // 2
countUp() // 3
```

You cannot access the mutable count variable directly.

Answer (score 2):

Another example would be using mutable state within a function so that you cannot observe it, and the function is, for all intents and purposes, referentially transparent. Take for example the following function that reverses a string not character-wise, but rather by taking individual text elements (which, depending on language, can be more than one character):

```
let reverseStringU s =
    if Core.string.IsNullOrEmpty s then s else
        let rec iter acc (ee : System.Globalization.TextElementEnumerator) =
            if not <| ee.MoveNext () then acc else
                let e = ee.GetTextElement ()
                iter (e :: acc) ee
        let inline append x s = (^s : (member Append : ^x -> ^s) (s, x))
        let sb = System.Text.StringBuilder s.Length
        System.Globalization.StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator s
        |> iter []
        |> List.fold (fun a e -> append e a) sb
        |> string
```

It uses a StringBuilder internally but you cannot observe this externally.

Comment: hi, I'm not sure if I understood the approach, for instance the hidden part, and what's the difference between character-wise and individual text elements.

Comment: Google ``TextElementEnumerator``; the Microsoft documentation explains it well. Regarding the hidden part: the fact that a StringBuilder (a mutable object) is used is encapsulated within the function, and from its behaviour you cannot observe any of the side effects it uses internally.